# Seat Cordoba 1.2 engine, 2005 - ignition coil

Tags: engine, ignition

Hi i have a little problem there. yesterday i found one of my cylinder stopped working, i swaped coil 2 to coil 3  (my car has only 3 cylinders), and i found that the coil nr 3 stopped working because when I've put coil nr 2 to nr 3 then the 2nd cylinder was not working. So it doesnt look like it's a spark plug or cables....

I thought it was only 1 coil gone, bought the new coil today, put it in and then there was still only 2 of them working, is it possible that another coil just went off? (i mean not the new one).

Maybe the spark plug in cylinder nr 3 is faulty and killing the coils? because the coil worked fine before i swaped it to nr 3 cylinder., then it was running a bit yesterday while doing the tests and i found out today that it just stoped working but it worked yesterday.

I've put the new one to cylinder nr 3 and it's working... so i don't know if this cylinder is crazy or what?, so maybe just bad 
coincidence?

new coil seats now in cylinder nr 3, i want to get another new one, but just afraid that cylinder nr 3 may cause the new coil to fail, is it better to change the spark plugs too?

sorry for my bad english..thanks in advance